# Kotlin extension function: unresolved reference

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I'm trying to create this extension function:

```
fun <T : RealmObject> Realm.query(myClass : KClass<T>) {    
    RealmQuery.createQuery(this, myClass::class.java)
}
```

This doesn't compile. Compiler says: "Unresolved reference: myClass" when I write

```
myClass::class.java
```

But if I do this:

```
fun <T : RealmObject> Realm.query(myClass : Class<T>) {
     RealmQuery.createQuery(this, myClass)
}
```

It works perfectly! I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myClass` is already a `KClass<T>` you can use [`myClass.java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html) member function like so:

```
fun <T : RealmObject> Realm.query(myClass : KClass<T>) =    
    RealmQuery.createQuery(this, myClass.java)
```

To simplify the usage you can actually make use of `inline` like so

```
inline fun <reified T : RealmObject> Realm.query() =    
    RealmQuery.createQuery(this, T::class.java)
```

And then use it as `val userQuery = Realm.query<User>()`